# PrintDocument doesn't print the full form

Tags: c#, printdocument

I want to print the **entire** form of size (1415x1000). But it is printing the form of size (1185x740).

I refer to the code from the msdn website:

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    public static extern long BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
    private Bitmap memoryImage;

    private void CaptureScreen()
    {

        Graphics mygraphics = this.CreateGraphics();

        Size s = this.Size;

        memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, mygraphics);

        Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
        IntPtr dc1 = mygraphics.GetHdc();

        IntPtr dc2 = memoryGraphics.GetHdc();
        BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height, dc1, 0, 0, 13369377);//13369376);

        mygraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc1);

        memoryGraphics.ReleaseHdc(dc2);

    }

  private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(memoryImage, 0, 0);
    }

 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Hide();
        CaptureScreen();
        PrintDocument myDoc = new PrintDocument();
        myDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new    System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", 1415, 1000);
        PrintPreviewDialog print_dlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        print_dlg.Document = printDocument1;
        print_dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But I cant get the complete form in the printout. How do I do that?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea about papersize. In the printpreview option itself i cant get the complete form. Please say, what can i do with the papersize @matzone

Comment: @matzone : I tried the papersize too it didnt help. I may wrong in using the papersize or there may be some other issue. Please help to fix this issue. Thanks...

Comment: @matzone : Added the code in the last fourth line

Comment: @matzone: papersize setting has applied but cant get the desired output.?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What I have to do with void **capturescreen**

Comment: What do you mean by **I want to print the entire form of size (1415x1000). But it is printing the form of size (1185x740)** .. formsize .. but formsize ?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble in explaining the question. By the way thanks @matzone

Comment: Hans passant is the best .... Got the solution @Developer ..

Comment: @matzone.. yeah... Great work by the man... Great support by you too friend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scaling used by the Graphics object created by PrintDocument is GraphicsUnit.Display.  Which maps 100 pixels to an inch.  That's usually a good match with the video adapter's dots-per-inch setting, the default is 96 pixels per inch.  So whatever you print on paper is roughly the same size as it was on your monitor.

That doesn't work so well for your screenshot however, your monitor is too big.  Or the paper you use is too small, take your pick ;)  You will have to draw it smaller.  Either use the Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle) overload or, simpler, use Graphics.ScaleTransform() to draw it smaller.  You probably also want to use Graphics.TranslateTransform() so the image is centered on paper.  Use e.MarginBounds to find the size of the piece of paper.  Some sample code for the PrintDocument event handlers that demonstrate how to make this work for any monitor size:

```
    private void printDocument1_QueryPageSettings(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.QueryPageSettingsEventArgs e) {
        e.PageSettings.Landscape = true;
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
        // Make screenshot
        var scr = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(scr.Bounds.Width, scr.Bounds.Height)) {
            using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(new Point(scr.Bounds.Left, scr.Bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
            }
            // Determine scaling
            float scale = 1.0f;
            scale = Math.Min(scale, (float)e.MarginBounds.Width / bmp.Width);
            scale = Math.Min(scale, (float)e.MarginBounds.Height / bmp.Height);
            // Set scaling and offset
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - bmp.Width * scale) / 2, 
                                          e.MarginBounds.Top + (e.MarginBounds.Height - bmp.Height * scale) / 2);
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
            // And draw
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tons of Thanks @Hans Passant.. It Works Fine.. By the way is it possible to make the taskbar not to visible.

Comment: Use Screen.WorkingArea instead of Bounds.

Comment: still a problem, didnt noticed, there is a **printing** dialogbox to the printed document. How to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sigh.  I'm not trying to write your application for you, this is just sample code that demonstrates techniques.  If you don't want to see a dialog then make the screenshot *before* you display the dialog.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry. If I'm irritating. Actually I didn't call the printdialog. And checked it manytimes and coundnt find how to reslove. And I'm very new to programming that's why these silly questions... Sorry Anyway...